# Two storyboards for different iPhones (3,5 and 4')

Tags: ios, iphone-5

I write application for a 3.5-inch on one storyboard and for 4 inches in another stroryboard. As a delegate at startup check under what device is enter in and from there method can be carrying launch storyboard or iphone 4 or iphone 5

(because the larger screen iphone 5, can I expands the functionality?)

Is it correct?

Comment: There is no answer to this.  It is neither correct nor incorrect.  It is just one way to do things.

Comment: When checking in appstore, accept this application? (writing this method)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do this. There is a button in the bottom left of interface builder that lets you switch between screen sizes, and using autosizing will adjust it for both screen sizes.

Comment: I now about this, but I'm interested in, or can I write the rules in this way? (apple is accept this?)
PS(Project does not allow otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Autolayout too

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @RohanKapur Your personal preferences have no bearing on the validity of the answer.

Comment: @borrrden Agreed. But you cant stop my assertiveness #YOLO